# Software to get better experiences with "modern" web page

Tags: web-apps, web-browser, security, privacy, sandbox

I take steps to minimize the amount of data that can be collected about me, for a variety of reasons.  For example, to reduce instances of "identity theft", hacking, etc.  I normally use an older version Firefox and a slew of extensions to accomplish that.  The older version is required to run most of the extensions.

I usually run sites like Amazon, eBay, LinkedIn, etc. in a private browsing (aka incognito) window.  It seems that these kinds of sites do not like being ran under such conditions, and will usually bog down the browser and/or my machine.  The sites may consume massive amounts of RAM (eg 200 - 600mb), or just generally decrease performance.  Amazon comes and goes with this problem, LinkedIn always has it, and eBay depends on the number of tabs open.  The solution involves closing that tab and/or restarting the browser.  Which is fine for ordering things, but no so good when I want to have easy access to LinkedIn (or some other communications site).

**What software (or configurations) can I use to manage/mitigate this behavior that I don't like?**

There are only so many different browsers, so each website can't get their own browser.  Not all browsers support all extensions that I'd need to run either.  Firefox doesn't easily allow multiple instances, so setting that up is technically-prohibitive, even for a tech savvy person.  The new containers feature in newer versions of Firefox is interesting, but then I'd have to give up some must-have extensions.  A whole VM seems overkill.  Docker might work, but I have a desktop OS, not a server OS.  I've looked into Sandboxie, but have not tried it out yet.

Chrome is out of the question, for obvious reasons.

Must-have features

- Runs on Windows
- fairly lightweight
- Free, low-cost, or 1-time payment

Nice to haves

- FOSS/libre
- Audited for security/privacy
- From a reputable developer/company/organization
- Linux support
- Android support